# LI gets clicked and shows another LI but not the rest on the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Rather green at this whole web dev thing. I have an HTML document that has a list of links (LIs) that when clicked, the area under it expands and more text shows up.

Example, you have a book title and when you click on it, information on the book appears under it. You click it again or click another LI on the page and it would disappear.

I have the styling fine, just can't seem to figure out the JavaScript or JQuery. Here's the HTML:

```
<li class="parent"><a href="#">The Wheel of Prison Operations: Useful Tool for Successful
Management of Security</a></li>
<ul class="story">
  <li>Publication, authored “The Wheel of Prison Operations: Useful
    Tool for Successful Management of Security”. June/July1999 issue
    of “Correctional Security Report” a national publication on
    correctional security operations.</li>
  </ul></br>

  <li class="parent"><a href="#">Use Of Force - Current Practice and Policy</a></li>
    <ul class="story">
      <li>Book on Use of Force in Prisons, September 1998, asked to co-author a book on use of force in
        prisons to be published by the American Correctional Association on use of force in US and
        Canadian Prisons. Use Of Force - Current Practice and Policy Published November 1999.
        Advertised as ACA “Bestseller” for several years.</li>
      </ul></br>
```

Here's the JavaScript (attempt):

```
    <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".story").css("visibility", "hidden");

    $("li").click(function() {
      $(this).children().css("visibility", "visible");
    });
  });
</script>
```

and or this too but neither worked

```
    <script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $('.parent').click(function() {
      $('.story').toggleClass('visible');
  });
});
    </script>
```

I'm open to suggestions on how to do this cleaner or where I might have messed up. Just trying to get the hang of this as it is kind of fun. Thanks in advance.

Comment: why dont you use collpasible plugin provided by jquery. you dont need an extra code

Comment: Where did you learn to write `</br>`? I see that more often, lately. Where does that come from? Is there a tutorial website somewhere that erroneously teaches `</br>`?

Comment: I can't remember where I found that. As for the plugin, I have no idea on how to do that really. Like I said, hours of trial and error and finally decided to see about getting help here. Should I just add padding instead of the </br>?

Comment: @TomG103 No, I mean you should write `<br>`. Or if you want XML compatibility, `<br/>`. But never `</br>`, ever.

Comment: Thanks for the note. I ended up going with <div> and <li>s and just added some padding in the CSS. I'll remember to just use <br> in the future though. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start from you cannot have `<br>` and `<ul>` as sibling of a `<li>`
Place BR and UL tags as LI childrens

After you fixed your HTML markup you can go for jQuery or even using CSS only

A far better HTML markup would be like:

```
<ul id="books">

  <li>
    <h2>Book 1</h2>
    <div>
      Book 1 story here
    </div>        
  </li>

  <li>
    <h2>Book 2</h2>
    <div>
      Book 2 story here
    </div>        
  </li>

</ul>
```

which than changes your jQuery logic aswell (at least regarding selectors, beside all the fixes to slide the book content story)

Here's a quick demo:

```js
jQuery(function($){

  var $allBooksStories = $("#books li > div");

  $("#books h2").click(function(){
    $allBooksStories.slideUp();
    $(this).next("div").stop().slideToggle();
  });

});
```

```css
*{margin:0;}
#books div{
  display:none; /*Hide all stories initially*/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="books">

  <li>
    <h2>Book 1</h2>
    <div>
      Book 1 story here
    </div>        
  </li>

  <li>
    <h2>Book 2</h2>
    <div>
      Book 2 story here
    </div>        
  </li>

</ul>
```

Comment: Awesome!! Maybe that was the problem to begin with. I'll fix that and post here to see if I did it right.

Comment: Placed the <br> in front of the </li>. There's a large <ul> that has all the other UL, LIs inside it. Is that wrong?

Comment: @TomG103 yes it's wrong. UL can only contain LI elements nothing else :)

Comment: Ah ok. So all I really need to do now is drop the large UL that holds it all in.

Comment: @TomG103 no, if you look carefully, on an H2 click I simply animate the `.next("div")` - so the DIV that's next sibling of the clicked H2

Comment: @TomG103 the UL#books is just a simple unordered list that contains lists (LI elements) where the title (H2) is visible and the immediate li's child `DIV` is hidden, and animation-triggered using jQuery

Comment: Thanks Roko!!!! That helped IMMENSELY!!!!! Any suggestions on text to read on that would tell me the proper way to do web dev?

Comment: @TomG103 :) you're welcome! -Too long to put in a comment. There's lot of good resources on Goog - First you need to master HTML and CSS, create a folder, create a document where you'll put all the findings, examples, links, tricks, cheatsheets; use bookmark in your browser; read books; watch tutorials; Regarding JS (a beast of it's own), probably the best would be to start with jQuery - to make your JS learning process quite fun and less painful. Once you start to use jQuery **a lot** - you'll inevitably find your self one day writing *pure* JS. Don't give up. Play, learn, play.

Answer (score 0):

Try this : You have to toggle only story `ul` under clicked parent `li` and not all story `ul`. Also did not see `visibility` CSS class in your post so used `toggle()` only

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
      //hide all story ul by default on page load
      ('.story').hide();

      $('.parent').click(function() {
          //find story under clicked parent, where $(this) is instance of clicked element
          $(this).find('.story').toggle();
      });
    });
```